# Regex Pattern for findin http in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

How can I extract the HTTP from this text?

```
"Text: Here's 2 free bonuses. http://blablabla.blabla/blabla "
```

**But the URL can also be another one.**

**Finally**

After I have the array, which contains usually just one URL, how can I add it to the above text exactly at the same position? But with HTML tag `<a>`

The results should look something like this:

```
"Text: Here's 2 free bonuses. 
<a href='http://blablabla.blabla/blabla'>http://blablabla.blabla/blabla</a> "
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388705/php-convert-url-to-a-link-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using regular expression, and more precisely [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). The matching expression can be something like :

```
$pattern = 'http://[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-/]+';
```

Of course, you can refine it for more precise matching, but this should do the trick. If you want to play with regex, have a look at [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/), it's a great tool for testing. Then, you can perform the replace ($0 corresponds to the whole matched string :

```
preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $yourString);
```

Comment: how can i used for an array without going throw a foor loop?

Comment: According to the doc (see the link in my answer), `preg_replace()` works with $yourString being an array of strings (returns an array).

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the trick:

```
$s= "Text: Here's 2 free bonuses. http://blablabla.blabla/blabla and some more text";
$s2= preg_replace('~(http://\S+)\b~', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $s);
var_dump($s2);
```

Comment: how can i use this for an array ?

Comment: According to the docs the third parameter can be an array of strings to apply the regex to: http://us3.php.net/preg_replace